# How to create a MVC Model from SQL Server 2014 Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have a function that takes start and finish date as parameters and returns a table.

In SQL Server when I call my function I use;

```
SELECT * 
FROM PV_GetLogByDT ('2015-11-01', '2016-03-04')
```

Now I want to use this function to create a MODEL for my MVC project. How can I do that?

When I do I get this error:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

Error

There was an error running the selected code generator:

'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'LTKB.CARD.Models.PV_GetCARDLogByDT_Result'. One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

CARDNOLIST: : EntityType 'CARDNOLIST' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
CARDPASSLIST: : EntityType 'CARDPASSLIST' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
CARDPINLIST: : EntityType 'CARDPINLIST' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
RESULTLIST: : EntityType 'RESULTLIST' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
CARDNOLIST: EntityType: EntitySet 'CARDNOLIST' is based on type 'CARDNOLIST' that has no keys defined.
CARDPASSLIST: EntityType: EntitySet 'CARDPASSLIST' is based on type 'CARDPASSLIST' that has no keys defined.
CARDPINLIST: EntityType: EntitySet 'CARDPINLIST' is based on type 'CARDPINLIST' that has no keys defined.
RESULTLIST: EntityType: EntitySet 'RESULTLIST' is based on type 'RESULTLIST' that has no keys defined.

---

### OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use EF it can help you. It explain step by step

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx